# MIPS Print String that was red without BREAKS

Tags: string, mips, system-calls

```
.data:
str2: .space 20 

#read string 

la $a0,str2 
li $a1,20 
li $v0,8
syscall

#print string 

la $a0, str2
li $v0, 4 
syscall


#print string 

    la $a0, str2
    li $v0, 4 
    syscall
```

The result:

EXAMPLETEX

***(I DONT WANT THIS BREAK... HOW DO I REMOVE IT?)***

EXAMPLETEXT

-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that service 8 adds a newline at the end of the input string, so you have to replace it with a null byte (0)
Add this code after the syscall that reads str2:

```
  # remove trailing newline
  li $a3, '\n'
newlineloop:
  beqz $a1, newlineloopend
  subu $a1, $a1, 1
  lb $a2, str2($a1)
  bne $a2, $a3, newlineloop
  li $a3, 0
  sb $a3, str2($a1)
newlineloopend:
```

It will search for that newline character and replace it with a null byte